# why test data is also involved in lightGBM train() and also used for calculate prediction error?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, lightgbm

I would like to use lightGBM to do a machine learning model training.

I checked the example at https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/examples/python-guide/advanced_example.py

I have some questions about the correctness of the code.

(1) What kind models can be created from lightgbm.train() ?
        https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.train.html
    It is a regressor or classifier ?

(2) Why test dataset is also used for training ? How this can assure that the test results are still valid ?

```
  # line 31
  lgb_eval = lgb.Dataset(X_test, y_test, reference=lgb_train,
                   weight=W_test, free_raw_data=False)
  # line 52
  gbm = lgb.train(params,
            lgb_train,
            num_boost_round=10,
            valid_sets=lgb_train,  # eval training data with test data !!!
            feature_name=feature_name,
            categorical_feature=[21]) 

   # line 84
  y_pred = bst.predict(X_test) # why x_test is also used to predict y? X_test has been involved in training the model !!!
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. You can train both regression and classifier models using `lgb.train`. It depends on the parameters, which you define, namely `objective`.
2. Test set (`valid_sets`) is used only for validation, it isn't used for training.